# How to show popup for desktop view and for the same in phone show as page using jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to show a div having data-role="page" as popup for the desktop view and when the same page will open in the mobile that should open as diffrent page. Can anyone help if it is possible.

thanks

Comment: detect the user agent and check if its desktop then open it as popup else open it as different page without applying popup code to it.

Comment: Thats what for desktop i am using simple javascript to open as popup ,but for lower resolution how to open as jquery mobile page using javascript.

Comment: i guess it would be on click of a button or element that you either open this div as popup or page, if that is the case then you can do changePage for jquerymobile else window.location.href if its plain javascript & jquery code.